# GROUP BY for continuous rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, grouping, gaps-and-islands

Given the following table:

```
ID   State  Date
12   1      2009-07-16 10:00
45   2      2009-07-16 13:00
67   2      2009-07-16 14:40
77   1      2009-07-16 15:00
89   1      2009-07-16 15:30
99   1      2009-07-16 16:00
```

Question:
**How can i GROUP by the field "State", while still maintaining the borders between the state changes?**

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, State, MIN(Date) AS Date, COUNT(ID) AS Count
FROM table GROUP BY State
```

results in the following:

```
ID   State  Date              Count
12   1      2009-07-16 10:00  4
45   2      2009-07-16 13:00  2
```

**but this is the desired output:**

```
ID   State  Date              Count
12   1      2009-07-16 10:00  1
45   2      2009-07-16 13:00  2
77   1      2009-07-16 15:00  3
```

Is this possible in SQL? I didn't find a solution so far...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  MIN(id) AS id, MIN(ts) AS ts, MIN(state) AS state, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := @r + (@state != state) AS gn,
                @state := state AS sn,
                s.*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @r := 0,
                        @state := 0
                ) vars,
                t_state s
        ORDER BY
                ts
        ) q
GROUP BY
        gn
```

Table creation scripts for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE t_state (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, state INT NOT NULL, ts DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT
INTO  t_state
VALUES
(12,   1,      '2009-07-16 10:00'),
(45,   2,      '2009-07-16 13:00'),
(67,   2,      '2009-07-16 14:40'),
(77,   1,      '2009-07-16 15:00'),
(89,   1,      '2009-07-16 15:30'),
(99,   1,      '2009-07-16 16:00');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how to do it with CTEs on MSSQL server

```
-- DROP TABLE MyLog
CREATE TABLE MyLog(
        ID          INT PRIMARY KEY
        , State     INT
        , Date      DATETIME
        )
INSERT MyLog
SELECT 12, 1, '2009-07-16 10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 45, 2, '2009-07-16 13:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 67, 2, '2009-07-16 14:40' UNION ALL
SELECT 77, 1, '2009-07-16 15:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 89, 1, '2009-07-16 15:30' UNION ALL
SELECT 99, 1, '2009-07-16 16:00'

;WITH   CTE
AS      (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RowNo
                , *
        FROM    MyLog
        )
, MyLogGroup
AS      (
        SELECT  l.*
                , ( SELECT  MAX(ID)
                    FROM    CTE c
                    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CTE
                                        WHERE RowNo = c.RowNo-1 AND State = c.State)
                            AND c.ID <= l.ID) AS GroupID
        FROM    MyLog l
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    MyLogGroup
```

Comment: as this is mysql related and i do not have any MS SQL server, i can not test your code.

anyways .. thank you for the effort and your contribution, it will help other people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://gcbenison.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/queries-that-group-tables-by-contiguous-blocks/) is a lengthier description of how solutions like the one offered by Quassnoi work

Answer (score 0):

I might be stating the obvious here, but if you're willing to make use of Transact-SQL, you can iterate through the rows of the table and build your own result set, which probably seems like a hassle, but it will definitely work. The iteration can be done [without the use of cursors](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/operations-no-cursors/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution for BigQuery:

```
WITH offset_state_table AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    date,
    state,
    LEAD(state)
      OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) AS offset_state,
  FROM
    `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`
),
grouped_table AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    date,
    state,
  FROM
    offset_state_table
  WHERE
    offset_state != state
  OR
    offset_state IS NULL
)
SELECT
  id,
  state,
  date AS start_date,
  LEAD(date)
    OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC) AS end_date
FROM
  grouped_table
```