# Find the period of over speed?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

Just something interesting come in my mind. Assume that we have a table (in SQL Server) like this:

- Location
- Velocity
- Time

for example:

```
Location     Velocity   Time
1            40         1:20
2            35         2:00
3            45         2:05
4            50         2:30
5            60         2:45
6            48         2:55
7            40         3:00
8            35         3:15
9            50         3:20
10           70         3:30
11           50         3:35
12           40         3:40
```

Assume that speed barrier is 40kph, the output is something like this

```
Starttime         Endtime
2:05              3:00
3:20              3:35
```

What is the best way to determine over speed periods (speed barrier is defined) ? My first idea was loading the table into an array, and then iterate over array to find these periods:

(Pseudo C# code)

```
bool isOverSpeed = false;

for (int i =0;i<arr.Length;i++)
{
if (!isOverSpeed)
    if (arr[i].Velocity > speedBarrier)
        {
            #insert the first record into another array.
            isOverSpeed = true;
        }
if(isOverSpeed)

    if (arr[i].Velocity < speedBarrier)
          {
          #insert the record into that array
          isOverSpeed = false;
          }

}
```

It works, but somewhat "not very effectively". Is there a "smarter" way, such as a T-SQL query or another algorithm to do this?

Comment: The point is that want to aggregate times of `Velocity > speedBarrier`, as `TimeSpan`-s? It isn't very clear. What output are you expecting?

Comment: The output I'm expecting is that the car is overspeed from "when" to when", not only TimeSpan

Comment: What's your model for how the vehicle's speed varies over time?

Comment: Vehice's speed is recorded by intervals. I ignore the acceleration, so we just rely on data on the table :)

Comment: Technically the second column should be 'Speed' and not 'Velocity' because there's no directional component. </pedant>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using CTE ([Common Table Expressions](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml)).

The query below works against the Adventure Works demo table of SQL Server (the "speed limit" being 7).

This is strongly inspired by another question on SO: [GROUP BY for continuous rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136597/group-by-for-continuous-rows-in-sql).

```
with CTE as (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over(order by SalesTaxRateID) as RowNo
        , *
    from
        Sales.SalesTaxRate
)
, MyLogGroup as (
    select
        l.*
        ,(select
              max(SalesTaxRateID)
          from
              CTE c
          where
              not exists (select * from CTE
                              where RowNo = c.RowNo-1
                              and TaxRate > 7
                              and c.TaxRate > 7)
              and c.SalesTaxRateID <= l.SalesTaxRateID) as GroupID
    from
        Sales.SalesTaxRate l)
select
    min(SalesTaxRateID) as minimum
    , max(SalesTaxRateID) as maximum
    , avg(TaxRate)
from
    MyLogGroup
group by
    GroupID
having
    min(TaxRate) > 7
order by
    minimum
```

Something along these lines should suit you:

```
with CTE as (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [Time]) as RowNo
        , *
    from
        <table_name>
)
, MySpeedGroup as (
    select
        s.*
        ,(select
              max([Time])
          from
              CTE c
          where
              not exists (select * from CTE
                              where RowNo = c.RowNo-1
                              and Velocity > <speed_limit>
                              and c.Velocity > <speed_limit>)
              and c.[Time] <= s.[Time]) as GroupID
    from
        <table_name> l)
select
    min([Time]) as minimum
    , max([Time]) as maximum
    , avg([Velocity]) -- don't know if you want this
from
    MySpeedGroup
group by
    GroupID
having
    min(Velocity) > <speed_limit>
order by
    minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't be *that* simple, or can it?

```
SELECT
  Location,
  Velocity,
  Time,
  CASE WHEN Velocity > @SpeedBarrier THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsOverSpeed
FROM
  SpeedTable
```

Comment: It seems that your query lists ALL overspeed records, instead of only overspeed periods. Don't have a real table to test now :)

Comment: @Vimvq1987: Yeah, that's why my answer was so reluctant. ;-)

Comment: just tested, your query returns all records, just added a new field (IsOverSpeed 1/0) :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following part to get some data ( I'm on compatibility mode 80 atm so I don't have a time field and am using an INT for the timestamp)

```
DECLARE @Info TABLE (Location INT IDENTITY, Velocity INT, [Time] INT);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (40, 80);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (35, 120);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (45, 125);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (50, 150);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (60, 165);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (48, 175);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (40, 180);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (35, 195);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (50, 200);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (70, 210);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (50, 215);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (40, 220);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (45, 225);
INSERT INTO @Info (Velocity, [Time]) VALUES (45, 230);
```

Assuming your Location are fixed points that has to be passed in order to complete the following will produce the desired output. I've broken it out into multiple Stages so as to make it clear what each part does.

```
DECLARE @Limit INT;
SET @Limit = 40;

WITH Stage1 ([Location], [Velocity], [Time]) AS (
    SELECT * FROM @Info WHERE [Velocity] > @Limit
), Stage2 (Start) AS (
    SELECT [Time]
      FROM [Stage1]
     WHERE ([Location] - 1) NOT IN (SELECT [Location] FROM [Stage1])
), Stage3 ([Start], [Stop]) AS (
    SELECT [Start]
         , (SELECT MIN([Time]) FROM [Stage1] WHERE ([Location] + 1) NOT IN (SELECT [Location] FROM [Stage1]) AND [Time] > [Stage2].[Start])
      FROM Stage2
)
SELECT *
  FROM Stage3
```