# MySQL - Group By Contigous Blocks

Tags: mysql, sql, contiguous

I am struggling to make a `GROUP BY` contiguous blocks, I've used the following two for references:
 - [GROUP BY for continuous rows in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136597/group-by-for-continuous-rows-in-sql)
 - [How can I do a contiguous group by in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610599/how-can-i-do-a-contiguous-group-by-in-mysql)
 - https://gcbenison.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/queries-that-group-tables-by-contiguous-blocks/

The primary idea that I am trying to encapsulate periods with a start and end date of a given **state**. A complexity unlike other examples is that I'm using a *date per room_id* as the indexing field (rather than a sequential id).

**My table:**

```
room_id | calendar_date | state
```

**Sample data:**

```
1 | 2016-03-01 | 'a'
1 | 2016-03-02 | 'a'
1 | 2016-03-03 | 'a'
1 | 2016-03-04 | 'b'
1 | 2016-03-05 | 'b'
1 | 2016-03-06 | 'c'
1 | 2016-03-07 | 'c'
1 | 2016-03-08 | 'c'
1 | 2016-03-09 | 'c'
2 | 2016-04-01 | 'b'
2 | 2016-04-02 | 'a'
2 | 2016-04-03 | 'a'
2 | 2016-04-04 | 'a'
```

**The objective:**

```
room_id | date_start | date_end   | state
1       | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-03 | a
1       | 2016-03-04 | 2016-03-05 | b
1       | 2016-03-06 | 2016-03-09 | c
2       | 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-01 | b
2       | 2016-04-02 | 2016-04-04 | c
```

The two attempts I've made at this:
**1)**

```
SELECT
  rooms.row_new,
  rooms.state_new,
  MIN(rooms.room_id) AS room_id,
  MIN(rooms.state) AS state,
  MIN(rooms.date) AS date_start,
  MAX(rooms.date) AS date_end,
FROM
  (
    SELECT @r := @r + (@state != state) AS row_new,
      @state := state AS state_new,
      rooms.*
      FROM (
        SELECT @r := 0,
          @state := ''
      ) AS vars,
        rooms_vw
    ORDER BY room_id, date
  ) AS rooms
  WHERE room_id = 1
GROUP BY row_new
ORDER BY room_id, date
;
```

This is very close to working, but when I print out ***row_new*** it starts to jump (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, ...)

**2)**

```
SELECT 
    MIN(rooms_final.calendar_date) AS date_start,
    MAX(rooms_final.calendar_date) AS date_end,
    rooms_final.state,
    rooms_final.room_id,
    COUNT(*)
 FROM (SELECT 
     rooms.date,
     rooms.state,
     rooms.room_id,
     CASE
         WHEN rooms_merge.state IS NULL OR rooms_merge.state != rooms.state THEN
                     @rownum := @rownum+1
         ELSE
                     @rownum
         END AS row_num
            FROM rooms
            JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS row
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT rooms.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS date,
                         rooms.state,
                          rooms.room_id
                    FROM rooms) AS rooms_merge ON rooms_merge.calendar_date = rooms.calendar_date AND rooms_merge.room_id = rooms.room_id
            ORDER BY rooms.room_id, rooms.calendar_date
          ) AS rooms_final
 GROUP BY rooms_final.state, rooms_final.row_num
 ORDER BY room_id, calendar_date;
```

For some reason this is returning some ***null*** **room_id's** results as well as generally inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Working with variables is a bit tricky.  I would go for:

```
SELECT r.state_new, MIN(r.room_id) AS room_id, MIN(r.state) AS state,
       MIN(r.date) AS date_start, MAX(r.date) AS date_end
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             (@grp := if(@rs = concat_ws(':', room, state), @grp,
                         if(@rs := concat_ws(':', room, state), @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                       )
             ) as grp
    FROM (SELECT r.* FROM rooms_vw r ORDER BY ORDER BY room_id, date
         ) r CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT @grp := 0, @rs := '') AS params    
   ) AS rooms
WHERE room_id = 1
GROUP BY room_id, grp
ORDER BY room_id, date;
```

Notes:

- Assigning a variable in one expression and using it in another is unsafe.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.
- In more recent versions of MySQL, you need to do the `ORDER BY` in a subquery.
- In the most recent versions, you can use `row_number()`, greatly simplifying the calculation.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This got me very close to what I needed and the first 2 notes helped me tremendously -- going to post my final solution below. I thought I was on most recent MYSQL, but I don't have access to row_number() which would have been delightful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff for giving me insights to get to this answer:

```
SELECT
  MIN(room_id) AS room_id,
  MIN(state) AS state,
  MIN(date) AS date_start,
  MAX(date) AS date_end
FROM
  (
    SELECT
  @r := @r + IF(@state <> state OR @room_id <> room_id, 1, 0) AS row_new,
      @state := state AS state_new,
      @room_id := room_id AS room_id_new,
      tmp_rooms.*
      FROM (
        SELECT @r := 0,
          @room_id := 0,
          @state := ''
      ) AS vars,
        (SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY room_id, date) tmp_rooms
  ) AS rooms
GROUP BY row_new
order by room_id, date
;
```